# Python process not responding with custom signal handler dealing with segmentation fault

Tags: python

Python builtin signal handler not working consistently when dealing with signal related to segmentation fault. By using `kill` command to send SIGSEGV to the process, it works correctly. But when an illegal memory access inside the process happens, which is also a SIGSEGV signal, cannot be handled by the custom signal handler.

```py
import ctypes
import os
import signal
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def receiveSignal(signalNumber, frame):
        print('Received:', signalNumber)
        return


    print('My PID is:', os.getpid())

    # register the signals to be caught
    signal.signal(signal.SIGSEGV, receiveSignal)
    # raise a segmentation fault internally
    ctypes.string_at(0)

    # wait in an endless loop for signals
    while True:
        print('Waiting...')
        time.sleep(3)
```

I expect the segmentation fault(SIGSEGV) raised by `ctypes.string_at(0)` is caught by the signal handler, but it didn't, and the process stops responding to `ctrl+c`, `kill -2 PID` and `kill -11 PID`.

However, I comment the `ctypes.string_at(0)` line, and send SIGSEGV with `kill -11 PID`, the signal is handled by my handler as expected. Besides, I don't understand that although the process doesn't respond, it keeps a 100% CPU usage.

What is the difference between these two cases?

Comment: In the actual violation case, what would you expect to happen after your signal handler returns here?

Comment: The signal handler here is just a demonstration, it doesn't matter what it does actually. The problem is it seems the process never gets caught by the handler.

Comment: string_at creates a new Python string, in a new memory location, completly independent of the memory location it was called with.

Answer (score 1):

Python can’t be executed in actual signal handlers (because there are *very* few actions they can take), so the underlying signal handler always returns.  That’s fine for asynchronous signals and “optional errors” like SIGPIPE, but for an actual program fault it’s meaningless because there is no valid execution to resume.  On some platforms, returning in such a situation just causes the same signal to be raised again, and an infinite loop results (without ever reaching the code that executes the Python-level handler).

Comment: Hi Davis, do you minding talking more on this? I met the same situation: SIGSEGV is not captured properly, and CPU utilization is always 100% for a core.

Comment: I find an explanation on official website (https://docs.python.org/3/library/signal.html): It makes little sense to catch synchronous errors like SIGFPE or SIGSEGV that are caused by an invalid operation in C code. Python will return from the signal handler to the C code, which is likely to raise the same signal again, causing Python to apparently hang. From Python 3.3 onwards, you can use the faulthandler module to report on synchronous errors.

Comment: @Dentiny: Right: this is the “always returns” part.  It is possible, with platform-specific code, to recover from some segmentation faults by having the signal handler use `longjmp` to abandon the bad execution, or to have it map memory that was just being touched.  Python signal handlers can’t do either of these things.